# Trailing questions marks in filename that is not showing up with echo

Tags: linux, unix

I have a short shell script that I wrote to just create backups.

```
#!/bin/bash
export MyBackup="MyBackup`date +%m-%d-%H:%M`"
echo $MyBackup
vi /tmp/$MyBackup.txt
rm -rf /tmp/"$MyBackup"
```

However, the filename that is created is something like `MyBackup12-09-08:46?.txt?`.  The echo command returns the correct string, but the vi command creates a file with ?'s.  How do I create the file without these?

Most of the issues ive lookedu p seem to talk about encoding differences, but I would think it would display incorrectly when I echoed if that was the case.

Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce the file that you're saying is created.  By any chance did you edit this file on Windows?  Perhaps there are hidden `\r` characters at the end of lines?

Comment: Also, you know you're doing `vi` on `$MyBackup.txt` but trying to delete `$MyBackup` without the `.txt` extension, right?

Comment: I ran `e ++ff=unix` and it seems like each one of the lines has a ^M at the end of it.  Ill try removing these and see if it resolves the issue.  I originally had it open inside of Atom in windows and saved it, but I didnt modify it.

Comment: Annnnd it looks like that fixed the issue.  Curse you Windows!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran e ++ff=unix and it seems like each one of the lines has a ^M at the end of them, so I removed them.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `vi` with `touch` to just create an empty file.

Comment: If I were to do something like mysqldump, would it create a file with ?'s as well?

Comment: It should create the file normally as you were expected.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, so should probably be a comment instead